# Ensuring Worldwide Legal Compliance for an App

Tags: internet, software, international, regulations

When selling an app, developers need to meet the legal requirements of each country in which they sell the app.

In practice, this seems like an impossible task because there are so many different countries and laws. However, many developers publish their apps worldwide.

Do developers have any protection from international claims because they sell their apps through the App Store (Apple, Google, ....) and not directly to customers?

Comment: Given that there are almost 200 nations, there are almost 40,000 country-on-country interactions to be concerned with. Obviously no-one is competent to advise you on all of those possibilities. You could reduce the scope of the question by indicating what countries you live in, so that if you have no connection to Mongolia, we could set aside the consideration whether Mongolian courts will enforce Tahitian judgments against you, since you have no connection to Mongolia. The general rule is, everybody ignores Africa, South America and most of Asia, unless they have a special interest there.

Comment: Also, plenty of apps aren't released world wide. But yes, most developers don't bother with laws in countries they have no interest in (as mentioned in previous comment), but you won't be able to pull that with e.g. China.

Answer (score 1):

### No

Developers either know the law or take the risk.